# Como abrir um formulário apenas com o nome do tipo

Tags: winforms, vb.net, reflexão

Tenho um **`DataGridView`** em meu formulário, lembrando que ele recebe o nome dos formulários do banco de dados MySQL.

Já tentei algumas formas para clicar no nome do formulário no **`DataGridView`** e abrir o mesmo, porém não obtive sucesso.

#### Exemplos da tabela

**Nome das colunas:**

```
id,  
nome - (nome fantasia do formulário) [Empresas],  
slug - (nome real do formulário na aplicação) [frm_empresas]
```

A ideia e clicar no registro no **`DataGridView`** e abrir o formulário, porém coletando o nome do formulário no **`DataGridView`** da coluna `slug`.

Comment: Tenho reunião em 5 minutos, mas acho que tenho a solução pra você. Se não tiver nenhuma resposta quando eu voltar, escreverei uma.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou ficar no aguardo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você saiba como obter o valor do `DataGridView`, vou ater minha resposta a como abrir um form usando apenas o nome do tipo.

Reflection resolve muito bem o seu problema e não é nada complicado. Supondo que eu queira abrir o form chamado **`Form1`**, que se encontra no namespace **`AbrindoForms`**.

<sub>**Nota**: é necessário adicionar o namespace `System.Reflection`</sub>

```
Dim slugform As string
slugform = "AbrindoForms.Form1"

Dim form = DirectCast(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(slugform), Form)
form.ShowDialog()
```

Perceba que é feito um `DirectCast` do retorno de `CreateInstance` (que é um`object`) para o tipo `Form`. Uma vez que todos os form's da aplicação herdam desta classe, isso é tranquilo e te permite chamar os métodos nativos do tipo `Form`, como o `ShowDialog` que uso no exemplo.

Comment: No lugar ai do '"AbrindoForms.Form1"' não consigo colocar a variável que usei para coletar o 'slug' do datagridview.

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta ou uma afirmação? Com certeza você consegue

Comment: `Dim slugform As string`
`slugform = dgvFavoritos.CurrentRow.Cells("slug_frm").Value`

`Dim form = DirectCast(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(slugform), Form)                                                                                    `form.Show()`

Comment: Legal. E qual é o problema?

Comment: Eu clico no DataGridView e coleto o nome do formulário, logo depois passo `slug_frm` no lugar de "AbrindoForms.Form1" e não funciona. Acho que estou fazendo errado :(

Comment: Você precisa conferir o valor da variável `slugForm`. Eu *setei* manualmente e funcionou de boa. Tenta colocar o valor da variável numa msgbox pra poder vê-lo, ou então conferi-lo via debug. O erro está em outra parte do código, o que eu te passei está funcional. **Note que você precisa concatenar o namespace antes do nome do form**.

Comment: Desculpe, realmente foi falha minha, muito obrigado @jbueno

Comment: A disposição. Que bom que pude ajudar =D